# What is the correct order of statement method calls using prepared statements?

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I want to make my db as secure as possible, and one of the things I've learned is to use prepared statements...so that's what i'm doing.

I just need a confirmation to make sure the order of execution is ok.

Does the following make sense, or am I missing something?

```
$sql = 'SELECT ...';
$conn = @ new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init(); // initialize a prepared statement

$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', ...);
$stmt->bind_result(..., ..., ...);
$stmt->execute();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    ...
}

$stmt->free_result(); // free the database resources for other queries
$stmt->close(); // close statement
$conn->close(); //close the database connection
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you don't need to call `stmt_init()` -- at least, it doesn't seem to be necessary, according to the example on the page of [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

You might also want to check :

- If the connection to the DB has been successfully established -- see the examples on the page of [`mysqli::__construct()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php), using [`mysqli::connect_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php).
- If the statement has successfully be prepared -- checking the return value of [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) before using it
- If the execution of the prepared statement has been successful, testing the return value of [`mysqli_stmt::execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Answer (score 0):

Two quibbles:

1. Don't suppress errors with `@`
2. Never assume a DB-related operation succeeded. Always check for errors cases, such as when you call `->prepare()` - your SQL statement may have a syntax error, yet you blindly proceed as if everything went perfectly. Same goes for the actual query execution - your query may be 100% syntactically correct, but fail due to external reasons.